# Android: Multiple entry point activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Requirement is pretty simple. First time user is asked to SignUp with a signUp screen activity. Once signed Up, he/she will be logged in to the application and second Activity is presented to user. Once user exit and re-launch the application I have to directly take the user to the second activity(without showing the 1st activity). I have tried conditional launching the activity, but the transition is not smooth.

Can you anyone suggest me a better way of having multiple entry point application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've always used the approach that you've described without any bumps or hickups in the transition.

Perhaps it's a matter of execution. I generally put my conditional (has the user already signed up), in the onCreate() method of the authentication activity. In the case that they have signed up, I will start the new activity and finish() the previous activity.

If for some reason this doesn't work, another approach which might require restructuring your code a little is the use for Fragments.

If you make the main activity use fragments instead, you can simply have a check in onCreate which will determine which Fragment will be displayed when the user launches the app, and you can just bounce fragments in and out from there out.

Comment: Justin, Thanks for the reply. I think using Fragments may be the best way to handle it. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using a **splash screen** on the beginning, and use it to make a conditional choose between `login activity` or `after-login activity`. With this implementation you don't have problems with smooth transitions.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your idea i implemented an operation to verify if user is logged in.

In my loginActivity i implement my `onStart()` with a verification based on my **`sessionManager`**. There i have methods like `isLoggedIn()` to check if the user data is still on cache, and `getLoginType()` for different kind of logins (admin, guest, ...)

If this stuff is verified:

`startactivity(new Intent(loginactivity.this, otheractivity.class))`

Comment: This is a great suggestion too.